# Encryption and Decryption of files results in a blank file when decrypting

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

Below is a simple snippet I'm using to test encryption and decryption of files.  What's happening is encryption is working fine - however, when I decrypt, the file is blank and I'm not entirely sure why.

I'm also getting a "padding is invalid and cannot be removed" issue but I can solve that with `Padding.None` but I don't understand why the file is null when decrypted. I'm using a simple text document to test.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.IO;

namespace EncryptionTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var Mode = "";
            bool Loop = true;
            while (Loop)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Encrypt or Decrypt? (E/D)");
                Mode = Console.ReadLine();
                if (Mode.ToUpper() == "E" || Mode.ToUpper() == "D")
                    switch (Mode.ToUpper())
                    {
                        case "E":
                            Mode = "Encrypt";
                            Loop = false;
                            continue;
                        case "D":
                            Mode = "Decrpt";
                            Loop = false;
                            continue;
                    }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("Must be E OR D");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("What directory do you want to encrypt?");

            var fileDirectory = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("What password do you want to use?");
            var passWord = Console.ReadLine();

            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(fileDirectory);
            for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
            {
                byte[] bytesToBeEncrypted = File.ReadAllBytes(files[i]);
                byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(passWord);

                // Hash the password with SHA256
                passwordBytes = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(passwordBytes);
                byte[] bytesCyrpt = new byte[0];
                if (Mode == "Encrypt")
                {
                    bytesCyrpt = AES_Encrypt(bytesCyrpt, passwordBytes);
                    File.WriteAllBytes(encryptedFileName(files[i]), bytesCyrpt);
                    File.Delete(files[i]);
                }
                else
                {
                    bytesCyrpt = AES_Decrypt(bytesCyrpt, passwordBytes);
                    File.WriteAllBytes(decryptFileName(files[i]), bytesCyrpt);
                }                  
            }
        }

        public static byte[] AES_Encrypt(byte[] bytesToBeEncrypted, byte[] passwordBytes)
        {
            byte[] encryptedBytes = null;

            // Set your salt here, change it to meet your flavor:
            // The salt bytes must be at least 8 bytes.
            byte[] saltBytes = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged())
                {
                    AES.KeySize = 256;
                    AES.BlockSize = 128;

                    var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, saltBytes, 1000);
                    AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
                    AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);

                    AES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

                    using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, AES.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        cs.Write(bytesToBeEncrypted, 0, bytesToBeEncrypted.Length);
                        cs.Close();
                    }
                    encryptedBytes = ms.ToArray();
                }
            }

            return encryptedBytes;
        }

        public static byte[] AES_Decrypt(byte[] bytesToBeDecrypted, byte[] passwordBytes)
        {
            byte[] decryptedBytes = null;

            // Set your salt here, change it to meet your flavor:
            // The salt bytes must be at least 8 bytes.
            byte[] saltBytes = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged())
                {
                    AES.KeySize = 256;
                    AES.BlockSize = 128;

                    var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, saltBytes, 1000);
                    AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
                    AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);

                    AES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

                    using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, AES.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        cs.Write(bytesToBeDecrypted, 0, bytesToBeDecrypted.Length);
                        cs.Close();
                    }
                    decryptedBytes = ms.ToArray();
                }
            }
            return decryptedBytes;
        }

        private static string encryptedFileName(string fileName)
        {
            string new_file_name = string.Empty;
            string extension = fileName.Split('.').Last();
            new_file_name = fileName.Replace(extension, "");
            new_file_name = new_file_name + "_encrypt." + extension;

            return new_file_name;
        }

        private static string decryptFileName(string fileName)
        {
            string new_file_name = fileName;
            new_file_name = new_file_name.Replace("_encrypt", "");
            return new_file_name;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing any bytes into your methods.  You need to pass the bytesToBeEncrypted array.  You were passing the bytesCrypt array in which is 0 bytes

```
byte[] bytesToBeEncrypted = File.ReadAllBytes(files[i]);
byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(passWord);

// Hash the password with SHA256
passwordBytes = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(passwordBytes);
byte[] bytesCyrpt = new byte[0];
if (Mode == "Encrypt")
{
    bytesCyrpt = AES_Encrypt(bytesToBeEncrypted, passwordBytes);
    File.WriteAllBytes(encryptedFileName(files[i]), bytesCyrpt);
    File.Delete(files[i]);
}
else
{
    bytesCyrpt = AES_Decrypt(bytesToBeEncrypted, passwordBytes);
    File.WriteAllBytes(decryptFileName(files[i]), bytesCyrpt);
}
```

Comment: Wow -- I feel sheepish.

Comment: No worries man, it happens to the best of us.  The hardest place to see it is when it's right in front of you ;)